# AngularJS - simple Count-Down using requestAnimationFrame (start/stop/restart)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, countdown

This is the little [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fM46M7HXbcTj7sFC5SHv?p=preview)

I am just trying printing count down seconds `from 11 to 0` and `then restart` it when finished.

The problem is it won't print seconds in the html also tried with `$apply` but i get digest error.
Also when restarting the countdown i got problems, seconds are not updated correctly...

How can i achieve this more easily?

Any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
(function withAngular(angular) {

'use strict';

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $window, $timeout) {

  $scope.countSeconds = 11;
  $scope.updateCountdown = function updateCountdown(ms) {

    $timeout(function() {

      if($scope.countSeconds === 0){
      $scope.countSeconds = 11;
      }
     else{$scope.countSeconds--;   }
     $scope.updateCountdown($scope.countSeconds);   
    }, 1000);
  };



  $scope.updateCountdown(0);



});
  }(angular));
```

Comment: will be too heavy to run this continously in the app? for all the user session... specially on mobile ...

Comment: having a continuous counter on the ui will have an overhead regardless of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `requestAnimationFrame`. Angular doesn't know that new value should be binded, moreover I don't think animation frame is required here. Try to replace animation frame with a $timeout, then angular will know that data should be rebinded. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FmpUmZVnvLXD0zG1bBlq)